# Tkinter gui freezes until function finishes

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I've a script which handles video uploads to google drive, so i wanted to make a gui for my python script with Tkinter. On user interface, i want the user to select a video from his/her computer to upload. On upload function i also refresh a text area to give user info about upload process.

The problem is, when user selects the file and starts upload function, the gui freezes  and no info is displayed on the text area.

When upload function finishes, everything turns to normal and it just refreshes the whole window, shows the text info i want to see **after the upload process**

I know i have to use threading for my upload function, since its a long running task but even after using threading its still freezing until the upload function is done.

Any help would be appreciated :)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import threading

root = Tk()
root.title("Drive Video Uploader")
root.geometry("400x500")

def main():
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.

    tokenPath='token.json'
    credPath='credentials.json'

    if os.path.exists(tokenPath):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(tokenPath, SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(credPath, SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open(tokenPath, 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
    root.label_0 =  Label(root,name="label_0", text="\n").pack()
    root.label_1 = Label(root, name="label_1", text="Please select videos to upload drive!").pack()
    root.button_1 = Button(root, name="button_1",text="Select Videos", command= lambda: threading.Thread(target=videoSelection(service)).start().pack()
    root.label_2 =  Label(root,name="label_2", text="\n").pack()
    root.text_1 = Text(root, width=50, height=25, name="text_1", state=DISABLED,bg="dark blue", fg="white", bd=4).pack()
    root.mainloop()


def videoSelection(service):
    selectedVideoPaths = filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir= os.getcwd(),
                                    title= "Please select a file:",
                                    filetypes=[("MP4 files","*.mp4")])
    textArea = root.nametowidget('text_1')
    textArea.configure(state=NORMAL)
    textArea.delete("1.0",END)
    textArea.configure(state=DISABLED)
    
    for video in selectedVideoPaths:
        textArea.configure(state=NORMAL)
        textArea.insert(END,"Upload started for: " + video + "\n")
        textArea.configure(state=DISABLED)
        uploadVideo(service=service,videoFilepath=video)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: At the moment, the videoSelection function contains both GUI and uploading code. The function that you create a thread for should not contain any GUI code and purely concentrate on uploading the videos.

Comment: I've seperated the for loop from videoSelection function and made it another function. Also changed the line of uploadVideo function  to threading.Thread(target=uploadVideo(service=service,videoFilepath=video)).start(). It didnt help @scotty3785

Comment: You should be running the entire loop inside its own thread. Pass the thread the list of video file paths and start the thread. I'll see if I can put a demo together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very rough example of what I've tried to explain in the comments. This should seperate the "long tasks" in to their own thread but still allow the GUI to be updated to show the progress.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import threading
import time
import os

root = Tk()
root.title("Drive Video Uploader")
root.geometry("400x500")

def main():
    service = {'test':'test'}
    root.label_0 =  Label(root,name="label_0", text="\n")
    root.label_0.pack()
    root.label_1 = Label(root, name="label_1", text="Please select videos to upload drive!")
    root.label_1.pack()
    root.button_1 = Button(root, name="button_1",text="Select Videos", command=lambda: videoSelection(service,root))
    root.button_1.pack()
    root.label_2 =  Label(root,name="label_2", text="\n")
    root.label_2.pack()
    root.text_1 = Text(root, width=50, height=25, name="text_1", state=DISABLED,bg="dark blue", fg="white", bd=4)
    root.text_1.pack()
    root.mainloop()


def videoSelection(service,root):
    selectedVideoPaths = filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir= os.getcwd(),
                                    title= "Please select a file:",
                                    filetypes=[("MP4 files","*.mp4")])
    uploadThread = threading.Thread(target=threadVideoUpload,args=(service,selectedVideoPaths,root))
    uploadThread.start()
    

def uploadVideo(service,videoFilepath,root):
    print(service,videoFilepath,root.text_1)
    print(f"Uploading: {videoFilepath}")
    root.text_1.config(state=NORMAL)
    root.text_1.insert("end",f"Uploading: {videoFilepath}\n")
    root.text_1.config(state=DISABLED)
    time.sleep(10)
                           

def threadVideoUpload(service,selectedVideoPaths,root):
    for video in selectedVideoPaths:
        uploadVideo(service,video,root)                           

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

Edit by TheLizzard: If you want a safer approach, don't call any tkinter function from the new thread. You can use global variables instead like this:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilenames
from threading import Thread, Lock
import time
import os


def main():
    global service, root, text_1
    service = {"test": "test"}

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Drive Video Uploader")
    root.geometry("400x500")

    text_1 = tk.Text(root, width=50, height=25, state="disabled",
                     bg="dark blue", fg="white", bd=4)
    label_0 = tk.Label(root)
    label_1 = tk.Label(root, text="Please select videos to upload drive!")
    button_1 = tk.Button(root, text="Select Videos", command=video_selection)
    label_2 = tk.Label(root)

    label_0.pack()
    label_1.pack()
    button_1.pack()
    label_2.pack()
    text_1.pack()

    root.mainloop()


def video_selection():
    # Get ready for the new thread:
    global text_to_insert, text_lock
    text_to_insert = ""
    text_lock = Lock()

    # Start a tkinter loop
    text_widget_loop()

    selectedVideoPaths = askopenfilenames(initialdir=os.getcwd(),
                                          title="Please select a file:",
                                          filetypes=[("MP4 files", "*.mp4")])
    upload_thread = Thread(target=thread_video_upload,
                           args=(selectedVideoPaths, ))
    upload_thread.start()


def text_widget_loop():
    global text_to_insert

    # Stop the loop when `text_to_insert` becomes `None`
    if text_to_insert is None:
        print("Stopping the loop.")
        return None

    # If there is text that we need to insert into the text widget:
    if text_to_insert != "":
        text_1.config(state="normal")
        text_1.insert("end", text_to_insert)
        text_1.config(state="disabled")

        with text_lock:
            text_to_insert = ""

    # After 100 ms run this function again:
    text_1.after(100, text_widget_loop)


def upload_video(video_path):
    global text_to_insert
    print(f"Uploading: {video_path}")
    with text_lock:
        text_to_insert += f"Uploading: {video_path}\n"
    time.sleep(3)


def thread_video_upload(selected_video_paths):
    global text_to_insert

    for video in selected_video_paths:
        upload_video(video)

    # Stop the tkinter loop:
    text_to_insert = None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `tkinter` functions from another thread. Only some parts of `tkinter` are threadsafe. Sometimes `tkinter` can just raise an error or even just crash.

Comment: @TheLizzard As I said, quick/rough example. A better way to communicate back would be through a queue but this would become a very long example very quickly. I don't believe what I'm hitting is unsafe on another thread.

Comment: @scotty3785 Unless you use queues in your answer, I really don't think OP will think of implementing them. I am yet to see a clearly defined list of the unsafe `tkinter` methods. I am pretty sure that most methods become unsafe in certain situations.

Comment: @TheLizzard Feel free to expand upon my answer.

Comment: @TheLizzard I like that. Haven't made use of Lock before. I've upvoted your comments and some of your other brilliant answers to share the karma.

Comment: @scotty3785 Thx. I have used threads quite a lot so I think I know how to use them :D